# possible to make text messaging with php have a constant "telephone number" value?

Tags: php, email, sms

i have an iphone 3g and can successfully send text messages using the PHP mail() function.  My issue is that for each message i receive, the "telephone number" associated with the incoming text message changes each time.  If possible, I would like to somehow make this number constant so that I can take advantage of iphone's ability to aggregate all text messages from the same telephone number -Otherwise my iphone would be cluttered with messages.  Is there a way to do this?

an example of the numbers I receive would be 1(410) 000-001, 1(410) 000-002, 1(410) 000-003, etc... can i make this constant somehow?

```
$message = stripslashes("new user just joined!");

mail("8185551111@txt.att.net", "Subject", "$message");
```

please let me know! thanks...

Comment: This isn't a PHP related question as any language would suffer the same problem. It is outwith your control.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is likely more to do with ATT than your PHP code.

Comment: makes sense, to take this in a new direction then, is it at all possible to use wildcards in creating iphone contacts?

Answer (score 0):

This is a limitation of the carrier's email-to-SMS gateway. There's no way to guarantee which number the message will come from.

SHAMELESS PROMO: You could use a service like Twilio (whom I work for) and get a phone number for $1/month which you would be able to always send from. There's a ton of PHP sample code to get you started. There are other SMS APIs out there as well so look around and find the one that you like best.

Comment: hey john, i actually found twilio right after i made this post haha, and i'm using it right now! it's great and incredibly lightweight at 4k for the php api.  ;)